# Is there a way how I can link HTML pages together and share information between them without a database?

Tags: php, html, no-database

Hi (English isn't my first language so forgive me for any mistakes),

I need some help with my code. I'm working on a website for a school project. I need to make a professional website with HTML/css/php/JavaScript. My subject is the videogames CS:GO. The main purpose of the site is to give information about how to play surtain maps/wapens etc. I wouldn't say that I'm good at HTML, but I know how to do things like a navigation menu and videos/positioning in css.

I currently have a index file and around 30 separate files containg information about the game. I know that I can use a database for this, but that isn't the purpose of this assignment. Almost every file is exactly the same besides the information/some Images.

I would like to know if there is a way how I can have one page countaing the code for my header/navigation menu/footer and another just for the information. 
I can keep it like I currently have, but every time when I edit something about a file name/location do I have to open every single file.
A example:
When I have a file linked in my navigation menu and I change the name of a file, let's say it's called map1.html and I change it to map_1.html . I have to open and manually change every single file.

When I did my own research I found the iframe attribute. But I couldn't get it to work successfully. So is there something else I could use? Maybe something with JavaScript or php? I also have no experience with JavaScript or php, so if you post some code please explain a little how it works and how I could use it.

In my head do I have this code:  . I know that this doesn't work, but it gives an better idea on why I  try do do. In the navigation-menu.html is only the code for the navigation menu and the css, nothing els. I searching for something like this. The purpose for the line is to copy everything in the navigation-menu.html file and display it.

An example of a page. I would like to have things like the  ,header, footer to be in a seprate file. Just for clarifications, the body class if for different backgrounds on each file

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Titel/Icon/CSS files-->
</head>
<header>
    <!--Banner/2 small images-->
</header>
<body class="GW-CT-AUG">
<ul id="navigatie_menu">
            <!--Other pages (history-about us-home(index.html) -->
    <li><a>Game Modes</a>
        <ul>
            <!--The different gamemodes-->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Maps</a>
        <ul>
            <!--The different maps-->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Wapens</a>
        <ul>
            <!--The different guns-->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Equipment</a>
        <ul>
            <!--The different Equipment-->
        </ul>
    </li>           
</ul>
<center>
        <!--An images-->
    <p class="tekst">
        <!--Information about the game-->   
    </p>
</center>
</body>
<footer class="footer" id="footer-aug">
    <!--footer-->   
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: You may try to save your data in a JSON. Also using XML used to be an option. You may use XMLHttpRequest to request text from a .txt file. This text can look like html

Comment: You can use the `localStorage` to store some data while being on `page1.html` and afterward access/ use it on the next page e.g. `page2.html` ... and it can be done using plain `JS`.

Comment: No, don't use frames or something. Don't try to do anything on the client side. This is exactly the job that PHP was made for!

Comment: @Bigga_HD That's not what he is asking for.

Comment: @enxaneta That sounds like something I can do, but I have no idea how I can use this. With data do you mean the information about the game?

Comment: @MartijnSchuman if you edit your question and add some code (keep it simple) I may be able to help you.

Comment: @enxaneta I added the code, I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a `header` file and a `footer` file you may create the content in a different file. First you create file for example `index.html`. Please note that I've added an id `ul_gamemodes` and another `ul_maps`.

In the javascript the function `readFile(file, parent)` takes 2 arguments: the file where you have the content (an URL) and the parent div where you want to put the content from the file.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!--Titel/Icon/CSS files-->
</head>
<header>
    <!--Banner/2 small images-->
</header>
<body class="GW-CT-AUG">
<ul id="navigatie_menu">
            <!--Other pages (history-about us-home(index.html) -->
    <li><a>Game Modes</a>
        <ul id="ul_gamemodes">
            <!--The different gamemodes-->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Maps</a>
        <ul id="ul_maps">
            <!--The different maps-->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Wapens</a>
        <ul>
            <!--The different guns-->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Equipment</a>
        <ul>
            <!--The different Equipment-->
        </ul>
    </li>           
</ul>
<center>
        <!--An images-->
    <p class="tekst">
        <!--Information about the game-->   
    </p>
</center>

<footer class="footer" id="footer-aug">
    <!--footer-->   
</footer>


<script>
function readFile(file, parent){
    var myContent = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myContent.open("GET", file, false);
    myContent.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(myContent.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(myContent.status === 200 || myContent.status == 0)
            {
                var myText = myContent.responseText;
                console.log(myText);
              parent.innerHTML = myText
            }
        }
    }
    myContent.send(null);
}


readFile("gamemodes.txt", ul_gamemodes);
readFile("maps.txt", ul_maps);



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Next you create a file named `gamemodes.txt` where you put the content you want to put in the `#ul_gamemodes`, and another file `maps.txt` where you put the content you want to put in the `ul_maps`. Please note that in the `index.html` you read these files:

```js
readFile("gamemodes.txt", ul_gamemodes);
readFile("maps.txt", ul_maps);
```

Now when you open the `index.html` you can see the content from those 2 files in place.

Since this wouldn't work in SO you may open this [Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/project/editor/358147926bb29c5cdf3c2aae94d6aac2#0)

Comment: THANK YOU!!. This was exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: I have one problem left, I can't change it to a class. You can't use an ID multiple times, but it doesn't work when I try to change it to a class

Comment: the second argument for readFile is the element id. If you need to use classes you have to use something like myElement = document.querySelectorAll("myClass")[n], where n is the n-th element with that class, and use myElement instead of the id

Comment: Can you plz give me an example of the code? I have no idea how i can implement this on my code

Comment: @MartijnSchuman I've updated my [Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/project/editor/358147926bb29c5cdf3c2aae94d6aac2). Now I'm using classes instead of id

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are over complicating it.

If you have PHP available but can't use databases, then you can do what you want with having a header, footer, and content and just `include()`-ing as needed at the right spot. Quite a few of my "static" pages at work (well, all of them honestly) look something like

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/global-style/header.php"); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/this_app/header.php"); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/this_app/left_side.php"); ?>
<div id="main_content" class="main_content">
Regular HTML stuff goes here!
</div> <!-- end main_content -->
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/this_app/right_side.php"); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/global-style/footer.php"); ?>
```

If you can only use pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript you either can use an `<iframe>` or do some trickery with JavaScript and http requests to load content from an external file/url into a `<div>` tag.

iframe - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

include via javascript - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

As for linking and navigation, you can always use either anchor tags or GET arguments on the URL to keep it all "single file" off index.php or index.html or if all else fails simply build a menu file to bring in with plain old href links to your content file with the header/footers applied.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create a PHP file where you will write variables like:

```
$SESSION['example'] = echo "SOMETHING... SOMETHING... SOMETHING..."
```

and call for them in each files?

For example:

You would like to create a div with logo of CS:GO then you write and stylize how does it should looks like and then input it into the `echo` statement.

like this:

```
echo "<div class='example'>LOGO OF CS:GO</div>";
```

Remember to insert it into the `<?php ?>` tags and ofc to start session :)

Comment: I tried to do this, but I could get it to work. In my head do I have this code: <link class="navigation_home" src="paginas/navigation-menu.html"> . I know that this doesn't work, but it gives an better idea on why I  try do do. In the navigation-menu.html is only the code for the navigation menu and the css, nothing els. I searching for something like this.

Comment: You don't want to use variables to store a site, especially not session variables.